# Ng-Grid Reference first column

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using NG-grid to display data in a table. I need to hide certain cells in a row if the 2nd cell in that same row gives back a certain response. I am writing a method that for each cell it will check to see what the value of the 2nd cell in this row is. My problem is I have no idea how to reference the value in that 2nd cell. Is it something like {{row.entity[col.field[1]]}}??? Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the column name, you can use `{{row.getProperty(\'columnName\')}}`.

You can look at the [row templates](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/) for an example.